# Why does subprocess return a string when called on stdout otherwise returns instance of CompletedProcess

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell, subprocess, command

When attempting to call run() on subprocess, I noticed if I call it as an attribute on stdout, I correctly get str as my type.

```
out = subprocess.run(['ls'], check=True, capture_output=True , universal_newlines=True).stdout
print(type(out))
#returns: <class 'str'>
```

However, upon removing the ".stdout", I get an instance of CompletedProcess:

```
out = subprocess.run(['ls'], check=True, capture_output=True , universal_newlines=True)
print(type(out))
#returns: <class 'subprocess.CompletedProcess'>
```

I have included the universal_newlines which should convert it from bytes output to a string format. universal_newlines is the more updated version of text=True. I tried swapping between them, gives me the same result.

It seems like .run() returns a CompletedProcess object and I had to access a string via the attribute stdout. I don't think that is correct, but that's how I am interpreting it at the moment. Many examples online I've noticed do not ever have to ".stdout" at the end of .run(), text=True / universal_newlines=True seems sufficient in other examples I've seen.

If anyone can provide some clarify, I would really appreciate it!

Answer (score -1):

It is [clearly documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) that the return value of `subprocess.run` is a [`subprocess.CompletedProcess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.CompletedProcess) object.

Perhaps in the examples you've seen, the code is not interested in checking the standard output of that subprocess, which is why it is never accessed. You haven't provided any examples, so we can only guess.